# Print structure member when passing it to function

Tags: perl

I have this structure

```
package StrukturaStudent;
use Class::Struct;

struct Student => {
sifra => '$',
ime => '$',  
prezime => '$',
brojBodova => '$'
};
```

and function

```
sub ispisiStudenta($st){
print $st->{sifra}." ". $st->{ime}." ". $st->{rezime}." ". $st->{brojBodova}."\n";
}
```

in which I want print the current student.

In another package I have an array of students and call this function as

```
StrukturaStudent->ispisiStudenta(@lista[1])."\n";
```

I don't get anything (only new empty line on console).
But when I call this from main

```
print @lista[1]->ime;
```

I got right what I need. So how to pass a single student from the array and print it inside function? Moreover, how can I pass the whole array and print every student in it inside a for loop?

Answer (score 4):

`$st->{ime}` is not the same as `$st->ime`. The first one searches for a key in a hash reference, the second calls a method.

You should always use methods with Class:Struct as shown in the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Class%3a%3aStruct). Also, you cannot declare named parameters in Perl:

```
sub ispisiStudenta {
    my $st = shift;
    print join(' ', $st->sifra, $st->ime, $st->rezime, $st->brojBodova), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried code above but got this error

Can't locate object method "sifra" via package "StrukturaStudent"

Comment: Read the documentation once more. $st should be a Student object, not StrukturaStudenta.